# SQL query multiple rows into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to change a SQL query that would normally return multiple rows with the same values into a single row?

for example, if my existing query returns this:

```
ColA ColB
1    AA
1    BB
1    CC
2    AA
3    AA
```

could I change the query to have only 3 rows returned and to place the 2nd and 3rd result for 1 into the first row, so that you'd have a row of: `1 AA BB CC`?

Comment: Look into `DISTINCT` or the `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: Also look into `union`.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @kmfmd: I reverted to my edit with the inline table. I think it explains everything perfectly and then you don't need to worry about image hosts being blocked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really nice but working(I'm missing  [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) from MySql):

```
SELECT ColA, 
       ColB=STUFF(
             (SELECT ' ' + ColB 
              FROM dbo.Table1 t2
              WHERE t1.ColA = t2.ColA 
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
GROUP BY ColA
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb6aa/6/0)

[ Edit: for any reason presumed SQL-Server ]

Comment: Yes, I am using MS SQL Server.  I will give this a try tomorrow, thanks.  Does that limit to 3 occurrences, though?  Is there a way to generate it in the desired format regardless of how many occurrences you might have?

Comment: @kmfdm: the size if the groups doesn't matter.

Comment: I suggest to use `value` function, like this - `stuff((select ' ' + ColB from dbo.Table1 as t2 where t2.ColA = t1.ColA for xml path('')).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')`, otherwise your solution is not correct for arbitrary strings, like 'A&A', for example. Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12940952/1744834 for example.