# Return single row from SQL Query of many tables with common UserId key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is the a better way of returning a single row from a SQL Query that has multiple tables with a common UserId Key? I also referred to [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958661/sql-query-multiple-rows-into-single-row) but result was not what I'm looking for.

Also, they are many users which are assigned with many ModuleAccess, many PageAccess, many catalogAccess, Only 1 UserType, And Only 1 SystemAccess. User table has go many users.

I tried this But did no work:

```
SELECT        us.userId, us.username, us.email, us.isAdministrator, us.status, us.FullName, ut.userTypeId, ut.typeName, ut.levelName, sys.sysAccessId, sys.adminDashboard, sys.accessName, sys.standardDashboard, 
                         sys.marginChart, sys.expiringChart, sys.increasingChart, sys.viewCatalogue, sys.importList, sys.exportList, sys.masterDataMain, sys.changesNeed, md.moduleId, md.moduleName, md.moduleUrl, 
                         pg.pageId, pg.pageName, pg.pageUrl, pg.pagePermission, pg.pageAccess,cat.catAccId, cat.HasAccess
FROM            dbo.mp_Users AS us 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.mp_UserType AS ut ON us.userId = ut.userId 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.mp_PageAccess AS pg ON us.userId = pg.userId 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.mp_ModuleAccess AS md ON us.userId = md.userId 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.mp_SystemAccess AS sys ON us.userId = sys.userId 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.mp_CatalogAccess AS cat ON us.userId = cat.userId
```

What I want is something link this:
[image]

This is my current result query :
[image]

Any One has a better way of Query this above SQL?
Thank you

_________________After few attempt_______________Query error

```
SELECT        
    dbo.mp_Users.userId,     dbo.mp_Users.username,     dbo.mp_Users.email,     dbo.mp_Users.isAdministrator,     dbo.mp_Users.status,     dbo.mp_Users.FullName,     dbo.mp_UserType.userTypeId, 
    dbo.mp_UserType.typeName,     dbo.mp_UserType.levelName,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.sysAccessId,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.adminDashboard,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.accessName,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.standardDashboard, 
    dbo.mp_SystemAccess.marginChart,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.expiringChart,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.increasingChart,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.viewCatalogue,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.importList, 
    dbo.mp_SystemAccess.exportList,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.masterDataMain,     dbo.mp_SystemAccess.changesNeed,     
    sum(dbo.mp_ModuleAccess.moduleId), 
    max(dbo.mp_ModuleAccess.moduleName), 
    max(dbo.mp_ModuleAccess.moduleUrl), 
    sum(dbo.mp_PageAccess.pageId), 
    max(dbo.mp_PageAccess.pageName), 
    max(dbo.mp_PageAccess.pageUrl), 
    max(dbo.mp_PageAccess.pagePermission), 
    max(dbo.mp_PageAccess.pageAccess),
    sum(dbo.mp_CatalogAccess.catAccId), 
    max(dbo.mp_CatalogAccess.HasAccess)
FROM dbo.mp_Users 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_UserType  ON dbo.mp_Users.userId = dbo.mp_UserType.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_PageAccess ON dbo.mp_Users.userId = dbo.mp_PageAccess.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_ModuleAccess ON dbo.mp_Users.userId = dbo.mp_ModuleAccess.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_SystemAccess ON dbo.mp_Users.userId = dbo.mp_SystemAccess.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_CatalogAccess ON dbo.mp_Users.userId = dbo.mp_CatalogAccess.userId
GROUP BY dbo.mp_Users.userId
```

Comment: In my opinion, this query is as good as it gets, in syntax readability and performance. Do you have any specific ideas on what do you mean by "better" ?

Comment: What exactly didn't work in your query?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, Thanks for your reply, By Better I mean that I want something to fulfill my goal. I have a web application page which need to display list of users with their access information. the user has to show only once not twice. If Possible to Group the Module Access, PageAccess and CatalogAccess which does add more columns in a Query. do you have an answer to that?

Comment: Can you show the result of your current query or the data present in your tables?

Comment: @Be1ng_Kr1Sh, My current query result I just added on my questions. Please have a looks

Comment: So you need to use a group by userID clause. Tell us: in case of multiple   Modula Accesses, PAge Accesses and of other fields with multiple values per userID, what aggregation should we do? Keep the maximum?minimum? Maybe it's guranteed they will be the same so it doesn't matte?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, That is what I think may work. But do you have an answer on that? like tried to answer to my question so that I may try it

Comment: In your new screenshot, we cannot see the usernames. Are they different? If they are, which one do you need to keep?

Comment: If the usernames are not different use distinct keyword

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, ok, I Will upload a new List with username  clearly showing. Thanks

Comment: @DhruvJoshi I tried the Distinct but did not work because it's the userID which is found in all other tables. so, maybe grouping or MAX() function will work but not sure how!

Comment: Nice of you to show the usernames and the email, but you can get in serious trouble with GDPR - please hide them again!!!

Comment: Usernames and email still accessible in edit history. Flagged for moderator attention. As hinted at by @GeorgeMenoutis, you are still in violation of GDPR (if applicable). If GDPR applies (and chances are it does), you need to report this to the proper authorities (*even if a moderator chooses to delete the entire question!*).

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Please tell me how to clean the history edit of my question? I want this question answer and no GDPR follow it behind. pls help. thanks

Comment: Only a moderator can clear the history (if it's possible at all). Nevertheless, the damage is done, and it should be reported. You should talk to your security officer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, All the Data used in this question was just dump and junk data. There is no personal information shared in this topic. Email, name, username, all that are just samples and does not exist. Hope this clear all.

Comment: It does clear it up, you could have made that clearer before though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
group by userId
```

in the end of your code, and then, at the select section,for all fields except userID, you will have to use

```
max(fieldname)
```

instead of fieldname eg

```
max(us.username), max(us.email)
```

Be careful, though. I proposed max() because I see that for every userID, the multiple values of your fields have the same value - however, you must be sure this is the case. If there is some field for which there are multiple values, you will have to identify in what way we should select one of these to present in the SELECT section.

Here are al the fields with max(), use with caution:

```
SELECT        
    us.userId, 
    max(us.username), 
    max(us.email), 
    max(us.isAdministrator), 
    max(us.status), 
    max(us.FullName), 
    max(ut.userTypeId), 
    max(ut.typeName), 
    max(ut.levelName), 
    max(sys.sysAccessId), 
    max(sys.adminDashboard), 
    max(sys.accessName), 
    max(sys.standardDashboard), 
    max(ys.marginChart), 
    max(sys.expiringChart), 
    max(sys.increasingChart), 
    max(sys.viewCatalogue), 
    max(sys.importList), 
    max(sys.exportList), 
    max(sys.masterDataMain), 
    max(sys.changesNeed), 
    max(md.moduleId), 
    max(md.moduleName), 
    max(md.moduleUrl), 
    max(pg.pageId), 
    max(pg.pageName), 
    max(pg.pageUrl), 
    max(pg.pagePermission), 
    max(pg.pageAccess),
    max(cat.catAccId), 
    max(cat.HasAccess)
FROM            dbo.mp_Users AS us 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_UserType AS ut ON us.userId = ut.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_PageAccess AS pg ON us.userId = pg.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_ModuleAccess AS md ON us.userId = md.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_SystemAccess AS sys ON us.userId = sys.userId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.mp_CatalogAccess AS cat ON us.userId = cat.userId
GROUP BY us.userId
```

Comment: I tried `(select userId, moduleId,moduleUrl, MAX(moduleName) as ModuleName from dbo.mp_ModuleAccess group by userId) md ON ut.userId = md.userId` but still casting an error. Please use my SQL Query and come up with a MAX() approach of the fielName. Thanks

Comment: check it out now (the funksoul brother)

Comment: This was my first attempt for max. Remember, ModuleAccess, PageAccess, CatalogAccess Tables are these that add more (same user) view repeatly` But I want all together in one place. like only one Line for user1, one line for user2, and so on.

Comment: sorry, i forgot the group by at the end - try now

Comment: show an Error: `Column 'dbo.mp_Users.isAdministrator' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` why is that?

Comment: The select might only have fields that are in the group by clause, else they must have an aggregation function (eg max) on them. You must use max(dbo.mp_Users.isAdministrator) , as for every other field.

Comment: Still not working, Same error, I did what you ask but with no help. I think the Group and the max() can work to gather but in my case seems not the case.

Comment: This error and what I am telling you is easy and definite. Post your entire query in the end of your original question.

Comment: Let me help you to understand what I clearly want. I want the List to show user1, has total(Module), has total(pages), has total(catalog) assigned to him in a single row, then follow by user2, user3, and so on.

Comment: ok, then for Module,pages,and catalog, instead of max(), use sum()

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis (and the error) were very clear: You need an aggregate function on **every** column not in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @HoneyBadger, the error says: `Column 'dbo.mp_Users.username' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` so,  there is no way around it. I tried to use MAX in every columns but was not successful.

Comment: @PatsonLeaner You get that error on the query you posted last in your question?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Please check the recent update. It's come from  there!

Comment: @PatsonLeaner, why did you not put an aggregate function on all attributes not in the `group by`, as you've been advised to?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I need an illustration to understand. I'm I did all of that but without success. Post an answer, perhaps it's maybe or may lead to the answer I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @PatsonLeaner, I can't give a better answer then this answer. Use `max()`, `sum()` or any other aggregate function on *every* column except `us.userId`, since that is in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can :
1 use LIMIT 1 when just one row of data
2 use a fairly typed column in the Join table and index it
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` won't work in sql server. What do you mean with point 2?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Limit Will Work, But Not according to what I'm looking for. I  first approach will be MAX() function and Grouping where the user has multiple entries

Comment: @PatsonLeaner No, `limit` doesn't exist in sql server, it's a mysql/Oracle (perhaps others as well) thing.