# Concatenate Rows for one column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using following query to extract appointment data:

```
SELECT app.subject, AL.locationName
FROM FilteredAppointment app
INNER JOIN appointmentlocation AL ON app.activityid = AL.appointment
WHERE app.scheduledstart='2013-07-06 15:00:00.000'
```

The output is as follows with 2 rows (same appointment with two different locations):

[image]

How can i modify this query to display only one row with two locations concatenated with comma like below:

`Column1:` (MZN; OTV)*...
`Column2:` Room1,Room2

Thanks

Comment: it is not duplicate to that question as I needed to populate the column values from different rows and same column. The post your suggested, the values are coming from other columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you need is [SQL Join and concatenate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940843/sql-join-and-concatenate-rows), there are many questions on SO about it.
There's no easy way to do this in SQL Server, but here some tricks:

Concatenate by using **select for xml**

```
select
    app.subject,
    stuff(
       (
           select ', ' + AL.locationName
           from appointmentlocation as AL
           where AL.appointment = app.activityid
           for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '') 
from FilteredAppointment as app
where app.scheduledstart='2013-07-06 15:00:00.000'
```

if you have only one record from FilteredAppointment to concatenate, you could use **aggregating into variable**:

```
declare @locations nvarchar(max), @activityid int

select @activityid = ???

select @locations = isnull(@locations + ', ', '') + AL.locationName
from appointmentlocation as AL
where AL.appointment = @activityid

print @locations
```

Answer (score 2):

This example will help you .. or wait until I makequery for you

```
  USE app.subject,
    SELECT      AL.locationName AS [Loc],
                STUFF((    SELECT ',' + SUB.Name AS [text()]
                            – Add a comma (,) before each value
                            FROM appointmentlocation AL
                            WHERE
                            app.activityid = AL.appointment

                            FOR XML PATH('') – Select it as XML
                            ), 1, 1, '' )
                            – This is done to remove the first character (,)
                            – from the result
                AS [Sub Categories]
    FROM  FilteredAppointment app
```

Comment: thanks but i guess answer given by Roman Pekar is working...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT app.subject, GROUP_CONCAT(AL.locationName, ', ') AS LocationName
FROM FilteredAppointment app
INNER JOIN appointmentlocation AL ON app.activityid = AL.appointment
WHERE app.scheduledstart='2013-07-06 15:00:00.000'
GROUP BY app.subject
```

Untested

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is nice, but MySQL specific. The post is tagged MS SQL.

Comment: Ah my bad, wasn't aware it was specific to mysql!

Comment: @jpw : OP wants in SQL Server.

Comment: indeed but you can find a workaround here : [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but I think this might do the work

```
select subject, 
       group_concat(name separator ',') Newcolumn
  from table
 group by subject
```

Comment: this is for MySQL not for SQL Server

Comment: Yes I didn't know that but I gave a workaround for msSQL in @Dale post